# Show remaining hours every 12th hours of the day

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript that shows remaining hours for every 24 hours and it worked well but i wanted to add a second function that show the remaining 12 hours for the day. how can i add this on my current script

```js
(function() {
  var start = new Date;
  start.setHours(5, 0, 0); // military time, remaining time until 5 


  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function tick() {
    var now = new Date;
    if (now > start) { 
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }
    var remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
    var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    var mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    var ss = pad(remain % 60);
    document.getElementById('time24').innerHTML =
      hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }
 document.addEventListener('click', tick);
})();
```

```html
<h2>Starts at 5am</h2>
<h4>Respawn Time every 24 hours</h4><br>
<b id="time24"></b> Until respawn<br>

<h4>Respawn Time every 12 hours</h4><br>
<b>??:??:??</b> Until respawn
```

edit:

For example, this script shows the remaining hours before 5am and reset (so it resets at 5am).

the second function I need is to show the remaining hours of the first 12 hours of the day and then reset.

so, if the remaining time is 24:00 for the first function, the second function should show 12:00

Comment: Can you share what you have attempted so far, please?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"remaining 12 hours"*? There are only 12 hours remaining at 12:00 noon

Comment: What should the timer show when there's more than 12 hours till target?

Comment: yeah hold on ill edit my question, kinda confused on my own question too

Comment: What does _"show the remaining hours of the first 12 hours of the day and then reset"_ mean? Do you mean `var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60 % 12);`?

Comment: there i edited my question, got really confused

Comment: Can you add some examples. Let's use 5 am for `start`. What are the expected results at 12 am, 12 pm, 5:30 pm, 5:30 am, 4:30 am and 4:30 pm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
var hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60 % 12);
```

to get the hours modulus 12.

```js
(function() {
  const start = new Date;
  start.setHours(5, 0, 0); // military time, remaining time until 5 


  function pad(num) {
    return ("0" + parseInt(num)).substr(-2);
  }

  function tick() {
    const now = new Date;
    if (now > start) { 
      start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
    }
    const remain = ((start - now) / 1000);
    const hh = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60);
    const hh12 = pad((remain / 60 / 60) % 60 % 12);
    const mm = pad((remain / 60) % 60);
    const ss = pad(remain % 60);
    document.getElementById('time24').innerHTML =
      hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    document.getElementById('time12').innerHTML =
      hh12 + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }
 document.addEventListener('click', tick);
})();
```

```html
<h2>Starts at 5am</h2>
<h4>Respawn Time every 24 hours</h4><br>
<b id="time24"></b> Until respawn<br>

<h4>Respawn Time every 12 hours</h4><br>
<b id="time12"></b> Until respawn
```

Comment: oh no not the result i expected ill edit my question to clear it up

Comment: @RJM I don't understand the problem. At my location it's currently 15:39 / 3:36 pm. Your "military clock" is set to 05:00 / 05:00 am. The timer shows remaining time `01:20:09 Until respawn`. It works as expected.

Comment: yes your code is correct, i messed up my code, instead of adding "% 12" i used "- 12" its working now, sorry for confusion